# Executing lifecycle method of backstack fragment problem in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have an activity with two fragment and want to be executed first fragment when its back from second fragment using back button. And i am using the `add()` when navigating first fragment to second fragment. Here is my scenario and code snippet:

**First fragment:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_fragment, container, false);    

        final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonChange);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonClicked(v);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View view) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_Container, new TwoFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("sdfsf");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Moving to **Second fragment** and here is the code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
}
```

The problem is that, When I am navigating from first to second fragment and then back again in the first fragment using back button first fragment lifecycle method is not executing. Instead of using `add()` if I use `replace()` then lifecycle method are executing properly. I know its the difference between `add()` and `replace()` but I want to use `add()` and also want to have navigation callback to handle some logic when I back in the first fragment using back button.

**Also tried below code:**

```
fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(
        new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onBackStackChanged: ");
                        // Update your UI here.
                }
});
```

But its also calling multiple times and creating anomalies.

How can I handle this? Specially handle some logic in first fragment when I back from second fragment.

Comment: addOnBackStackChangedListener should work well, probably you set several listeners instead of one?

Comment: For me when i am navigating from first to second fragment its calling and when i back to first fragment its calling again. Basilica, its calling every time the backstack changes.

Comment: That's right, just take the top entry name using getBackStackEntryAt and call getName(). According to the name you can figure out what fragment is the current.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to set result when you're done with the second fragment that essentially tells the first fragment to "resume" via its onActivityResult method.

When you create an instance of Fragment B, call [#setTargetFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#settargetfragment) and pass in Fragment A as your target fragment. Then when Fragment B is done and going to return to Fragment A, before it exits, you will set the result of it for Fragment A by calling:

```
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), RESULT_FRAGMENT_B_FINISHED,null)
///// horizontal scroll padding
```

Note that ***RESULT_FRAGMENT_B_FINISHED*** would be some static integer you define somewhere, like

```
public static final int RESULT_FRAGMENT_B_FINISHED = 123123;
```

Now in Fragment A all you need to do is override onActivityResult and check that the request code matches the request code integer from setTargetFragment and the result code also matches RESULT_FRAGMENT_B_FINISHED, if so you can run the code that would have been fired from onResume().

[#getTargetFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getTargetFragment())

[#onActivityResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#gettargetrequestcode)

[#getTargetRequestCode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

Comment: When i am navigating fragment A to fragment B using         `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_Container, new TwoFragment());`
 my fragment A lifecycle method is not changing even when i am back to fragment A from backstack its not changing also. So, how can i execute those method.

Comment: You can't get lifecycle events with fragmentTransaction#add(). This is because you can technically have multiple fragments showing on a single activity. Android doesn't know if its fullscreen or a portion of the screen. When calling add, you're telling android I'm showing both of these fragments.  If you use fragmentTransaction#replace() you will get those lifecycle events because you're telling android I'm removing fragment a and adding fragment b.

Comment: I know that using replace() it can be fixed but i don't to create and destroy fragment A every time switching between A and B.

Comment: I had a similar problem not to long ago. I decided to just let fragment a sit in the background and continue listening and updating its view. There was no harm in performance and the user could return with the UI representing the latest data.

Comment: If Fragment A is causing disruption on Fragment B, like say it shows a dialog or switches to a Fragment C during an event, you could have it check to see if its the top fragment in the backstack before letting it continue.

Comment: Basically , I have lots of fragment in a single activity and want to track each and every fragment when back from backstack. That's the requirement. That's the reason i have to track when a fragment coming from its backstack.

Comment: Hmm it sounds like the addOnBackStackChangedListener would be better for you then. When it fires just get the top fragment on the back stack and track the class name of it.

Comment: Yes. I tried this also but its executing each time backstack change that's why looking for some better solution.

Comment: If you specifically need to catch when fragment A returns from fragment B, you can use my solution. When you get the activity result you can just treat it as fragment A being shown when you track it. You wont get the lifecycle event, but you can call the same methods as it would.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing data between the two fragments I recommend you to use a SharedViewModel.

The idea is that the first fragment observe some data for changes and the second one edit this data.

Example:

Shared ViewModel

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {

  private final MutableLiveData<Item> selected = new 
  MutableLiveData<Item>();

  public void select(Item item) {
      selected.setValue(item);
  }

  public LiveData<Item> getSelected() {
      return selected;
  }
}
```

First fragment

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      SharedViewModel model = 
      ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
      model.getSelected().observe(this, { item ->
         // Update the UI.
      });
  }
}
```

Second fragment

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      SharedViewModel model = 
      ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
      model.select(new Item("value 1","value 2");
  }
}
```

You can read about ViewModels, LiveData and Architecture components starting from here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#java

This answer is assuming that you want to execute some logic based on some data change. If it's not the case, you can explain what kind of logic do you want to execute and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually i want to track my fragment when the fragment gets visible from backstack. Its nothing related to logic mainly view tracking requirements.